Is it safe to specialize `std::numeric_limits` for `std::byte`?
I was surprised that std::numeric_limits<std::byte>::digits returns 0, when I was expecting 8. I believe this is due to lacking specialization for std::byte hence defaulting to the, well, default implementation that return 0 in this case.
Since the standard doesn't seem to do it, is it safe to specialize std::numeric_limits for std::byte myself for my code?

Why won't you create your own numeric_limits? Why do you want to mess with std::numeric_limits?

@freakish My generic template uses std::numeric_limits. I trust it to work for other integral types, and also std::byte.

Use std::numeric_limit<std::underlying_type_t<std::byte>>, or directly std::numeric_limit<unsigned char>.

Specializing std template is only possible/legal for some template, and better to be done for your own types.

std::byte is not considered an arithmetic type, so there is no std::numeric_limits<std::byte>, and std::to_integer is needed to assign it an integer.

std::byte appears to be a strange animal, not one of the numeric types at all.  So numeric_limits is not defined for it on that basis.  I'd use uint8_t instead.

Yes, IFF it is not actually declared by your Standard Library. (I think!) https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std (But I just saw that std::byte is not arithmetic, so... no. Fooey.

It may be better to use std::uint8_t or std::int8_t if is should be used as arithmetic type, or make a custom numeric limits template, that redirects to std::numeric_limits in cases other than std::byte

Note that std::byte "... but unlike unsigned char, it is not a character type and is not an arithmetic type. std::byte models a mere collection of bits, supporting only bitshift operations with an integer, and bitwise and comparison operations with another std::byte.". So a specialization of std::numeric_limit does not make sense.

numeric.limits#general-6: "Non-arithmetic standard types, such as complex, shall not have specializations."

It is not safe, in fact it is not allowed. [namespace.std]/2 states

Unless explicitly prohibited, a program may add a template specialization for any standard library class template to namespace std provided that

the added declaration depends on at least one program-defined type, and
the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template.155


and it is the first bullet point that disallows this.  std::byte is a library type, not a program-defined type.

What you can do is use underlying_type_t<std::byte> as that will be a built in arithmetic type.  That will give you:
std::numeric_limits<std::underlying_type_t<std::byte>>::digits


std::numeric_limits<std::underlying_type_t<std::byte>>::digits is a bit unnecessarily complex. This is always guaranteed to be CHAR_BIT.

@user17732522 In this case yes, but if the user has a different enumeration type then this still works.

Yes, but care needs to be taken that it isn't an unscoped enumeration without fixed underlying type. In that case the underlying type may have a wider value range than the enumeration type.

@user17732522 in either case, underlying type determines the storage properties of the enumeration. The named values are not the only well-defined values for an enumeration object; explicit cast from underlying type is always well-defined, even if the result doesn't have any enumeration name. That's exactly how std::byte is defined and used. It's an empty enum with std::uint8_t as the underlying type.

@Red.Wave "explicit cast from underlying type is always well-defined, even if the result doesn't have any enumeration name.": No, that's explicitly not true for enumeration types without so-called fixed underlying type, i.e. enumerations declared with enum instead of class enum and without explicit underlying type (enum XX : YY). In that case the value range is restricted per https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.enum#8.sentence-2 and casting an underlying types value outside the range to the enumeration type is UB, also per https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#9.sentence-3.
